# Get all results that contain the largest value in table

Tags: java, postgresql, querydsl

Let's say I have a very simple table called *test*:

```
ID        AGE         NAME
1         12          Bob
1         13          Bob
2         13          John
3         9           Michael
3         11          Michael
```

I want to return all results that have the largest `AGE` in the table. So for this case, the result would be the entities with the age 13:

```
ID        AGE         NAME
1         13          Bob
2         13          John
```

I would think something like this should exist, my thought process would have been the following (even though I know the syntax would not work):

```
connection.getSqlQuery()
                .from(test)
                .max(test.age)
                .list(test.id, test.age, test.name);
```

What would be the proper query for this?

Comment: a group by age and ID/Name, and a where with age = (select max(age).... )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a subquery and use it in your where clause:

```
// Aggregate to get the maximum age
var subQuery = connection.getSqlQuery()
    .select(test.age.max())
    .from(test);

connection.getSqlQuery()
    .from(test)
    .where(test.age.eq(subQuery))
    .list(test.id, test.age, test.name);
```

If you use JPA, you can also use `var subQuery = JPAExpressions.select(...`